# Laravel: Searching in MySQL database with items from Form::textarea

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm trying to query a MySQL database for items coming from a textarea. My controller's `store()` function has the following code:

```
// [...] validation is done here and assumed ok

foreach(explode("\n", Input::get('itemlist')) as $line) {
    $item = preg_split('/(?<=\d) (?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)/i', $line);
    if (isset($item[1])) { 
        echo 'Looking for ' . $item[1];
        $itemObj = DB::table('items')->select('name', 'id')->where('name', '=', trim($item[1], "\r"))->first();
        var_dump($itemObj);
    }
}
```

The data received from `Input::get('itemlist')` is a list of items and amount, something like:

```
5 apples
2 oranges
1 banana
```

The `Looking for ...` part displays the item names properly. Also, the `var_dump` will actually show the proper result for the **last** thing searched for, everything else is just `'null'`.

Is there something about `DB:table` that stops from doing queries in a loop like this? Should I do this some other way? Thanks!

**EDIT** Turns out there were trailing '\r' after each line except the last one so the query was for "Some Item\r" and not "Some Item". Fixed it above!

Comment: I suggest you install a [profiler](https://github.com/loic-sharma/profiler) or if you are using Google Chrome install [Clockwork](http://matthewhailwood.co.nz/running-like-clockwork-laravel-debugging-in-google-chrome/) both if which will show you the actual query being run. `DB::table` should not affect the query in this way, but it may be being escaped incorrectly. So try one of these and then show us the queries returned.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out there was a trailing '\r' at the end of each ``$item[1]`` until the very last one so the query was for "Some Item\r" hence why it wouldn't be found. I installed Clockwork and found the problem right away. Thanks!